# MSSQL Service failed to start on ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu

Every time i checked the MSSQL service is failing i have over 5 GB memory on my virtual server. I have changed the sql port to 1533.

> **r*****k:~# sudo systemctl status mssql-server**

*● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-11-17 15:39:39 UTC; 1min 37s ago*

```
Process: 4906 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=exited, status=255)
Main PID: 4906 (code=exited, status=255)

Nov 17 15:39:39 SV0*****com systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Unit entered failed state.

Nov 17 15:39:39 SV0*****com systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Nov 17 15:39:39 SV0*****.com systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

Nov 17 15:39:39 SV0*****.com systemd[1]: Stopped Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.

Nov 17 15:39:39 SV0*****.com systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.

Nov 17 15:39:39 SV0*****.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
```

> **r*****k:/var/opt/mssql# cat mssql.conf**

```
> [EULA] accepteula = Y</br>
> 
> [network] ipaddress = 6*.*1.1*2.*8 kerberoskeytabfile =
> /var/opt/mssql/secrets/mssql.keytab tcpport = 1533
> 
> [memory] memorylimitmb = 3328
> 
> [filelocation] defaultdatadir = /tmp/data
```

Anyone can help to stable the mssql service on the vm.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-troubleshooting-guide Clearly people go to Microsoft for help directly.

Answer (score 1):

Does your Ubuntu server have the firewall enabled? If so, it may be blocking port 1533, which is preventing the service from starting on that custom port.

You may want to look in /var/log/messages for additional information as well.